# How can I apply an arbitrary function under an existential wrapper?

Tags: haskell, existential-type

I'm trying to write a function (called `hide` here), which can apply a sufficiently polymorphic function inside an existential wrapper (or lift functions to work on wrappers with hidden types; hence "hide"):

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs
           , RankNTypes
  #-}

data Some f
  where Some :: f a -> Some f


hide :: (forall a. f a -> g b) -> Some f -> Some g
hide f (Some x) = Some (f x)


data Phantom a = Phantom

cast :: Phantom a -> Phantom b
cast Phantom = Phantom

works :: Some Phantom -> Some Phantom
works = hide cast


doesn't :: Functor f => Some f -> Some f
doesn't = hide (fmap $ \x -> [x])
{-
foo.hs:23:17:
    Couldn't match type ‘b0’ with ‘[a]’
      because type variable ‘a’ would escape its scope
    This (rigid, skolem) type variable is bound by
      a type expected by the context: f a -> f b0
      at foo.hs:23:11-33
    Expected type: f a -> f b0
      Actual type: f a -> f [a]
    In the first argument of ‘hide’, namely ‘(fmap $ \ x -> [x])’
    In the expression: hide (fmap $ \ x -> [x])
    In an equation for ‘doesn't’: doesn't = hide (fmap $ \ x -> [x])
Failed, modules loaded: none.
-}


but :: Functor f => Some f -> Some f
but = hide' (fmap $ \x -> [x])
  where hide' :: (forall a. f a -> g [a]) -> Some f -> Some g
        hide' f (Some x) = Some (f x)
```

So I pretty much understand why this is happening; `works` shows that `hide` does in fact work when the return type is completely unrelated to the input type, but in `doesn't` I'm calling `hide` with an argument of type `a -> [a]`. `hide` is supposed to get to "choose" the type `a` (`RankNTypes`), but `b` is ordinarily polymorphic. When `b` in fact depends on `a`, `a` could leak out.

But in the context where I'm actually calling it, `a` doesn't in fact leak out; I immediately wrap it up in `Some`. And in fact I can write an alternate `hide'` that accepts specifically `a -> [a]` functions and works **with the exact same implementation**, just a different type signature.

Is there any way I can type the implementation `hide f (Some x) = Some (f x)` so that it works more generally? Really I'm interested in lifting functions with type `a -> q a`, where `q` is some arbitrary type function; i.e. I expect the return type to depend on `a`, but I don't care how it does so. There probably are use cases where `q a` is a constant (i.e. the return type doesn't depend on `a`), but I imagine they'll be much rarer.

This example is pretty silly, obviously. In my real use case I have a GADT `Schema a` that roughly speaking represents types in an external type system; the phantom parameter gives a Haskell type that could be used to represent values in the external type system. I need that phantom parameter to keep everything type safe, but sometimes I construct `Schema`s based on runtime data, in which case I don't know what that parameter type is.

So I appear to need another type which is agnostic about the type parameter. Rather than make (yet) another parallel type, I was hoping to use a simple existential wrapper like `Some` to construct it from `Schema`, and be able to lift functions of type `forall a. Schema a -> Schema b` to `Some Schema -> Some Schema`. So if I have an XY problem and I'd be better of using some other means of passing around `Schema a` for unknown `a`, that would also solve my problem.

Comment: If you type it as `hide :: (forall a. f a -> g (q a)) -> Some f -> Some g`, `doesn't` type checks but that might not be as general as you're looking for (you can't use it when `q ~ Id`, where `type Id a = a` for instance).

Comment: @DavidYoung I'll try that and see how I go; I wouldn't like it so much as a combinator to expose to users of my library, but it may well meet most of my internal needs (since to be sufficiently polymorphic in `a`, I'm usually just wrapping it something else polymorphic).

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if any of this would help out much with this problem, but this kinda thing reminds me a lot of this package I'm starting to develop for working with existentials (mostly focused on lists of existentials right now though): https://github.com/roboguy13/anylist/. The stuff that's commented out at the bottom is probably most likely to apply to this (in particular, I'm thinking of the `Existential` instance of the polykinded `Functor` class), but it probably isn't functional yet (but I don't totally remember).

Answer (score 4):

As **David Young** says, you can write

```
hide' :: (forall a. f a -> g (q a)) -> Some f -> Some g
hide' f (Some x) = Some (f x)

does :: Functor f => Some f -> Some f
does = hide' (fmap (:[]))
```

but instead of making `hide` fmap-like, you can make it bind-like:

```
hide'' :: (forall a. f a -> Some g) -> Some f -> Some g
hide'' f (Some x) = f x

does :: Functor f => Some f -> Some f
does = hide'' (Some . fmap (:[]))
```

But this is a bit boilerplateable.

Or, more generally

```
elim :: (forall a. f a -> c) -> Some f -> c
elim f (Some x) = f x
```

Comment: I like `elim` a lot. It partially defeats the purpose here, since my aim is to have a combinator that lifts existing `Schema a -> Schema b` operations to `Some Schema -> Some Schema` ones, so I don't have to manually unwrap and rewrap `Some` everywhere; `elim` saves me from manually unwrapping, but not rewrapping.

Comment: @Ben, you can also define synonyms like `sfmap f = Some . fmap f`. I think `hide'` would be sufficient in most cases. The problem with `q ~ Id` (besides the fact that you can define another `hide :: (forall a. f a -> g a) -> Some f -> Some g)` can be solved by defining `Id` as a `newtype` at the cost of the same wrapping-unwrapping.

Comment: re `sfmap`: True, but then redefining an existential-flavoured version of every one of my functions is something I can do without needing any version of `hide`; just write `f' (Some x) = Some (f x)` for each `f` I'm interested in.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how useful this is for your larger use-case as you'd have to refactor all your existing operations to use continuation passing style, but continuations can be used to implement a `hide` that works for both of your examples and keeps `b` completely generic.

```
hide :: (forall r a. f a -> (forall b. g b -> r g) -> r g) -> Some f -> Some g
hide f (Some x) = f x Some

cast :: Phantom a -> (forall b. Phantom b -> r Phantom) -> r Phantom
cast Phantom f = f Phantom

works :: Some Phantom -> Some Phantom
works = hide cast

alsoWorks :: Functor f => Some f -> Some f
alsoWorks = hide (\a f -> f $ fmap (\x -> [x]) a)
```

You can make it somewhat nicer by factoring out the CPS-conversion which allows you to more easily use existing functions like your original `cast`:

```
hide :: (forall r a. f a -> (forall b. g b -> r g) -> r g) -> Some f -> Some g
hide f (Some x) = f x Some

cps :: (f a -> g b) -> (f a -> (forall c. g c -> r) -> r)
cps f a c = c (f a)

cast :: Phantom a -> Phantom b
cast Phantom = Phantom

works :: Some Phantom -> Some Phantom
works = hide $ cps cast

alsoWorks :: Functor f => Some f -> Some f
alsoWorks = hide $ cps $ fmap (\x -> [x])
```